# Would Poker (with *Zero* real-world currency involved) in an M-Rated (18+) Online game be constituted Online Gambling?

Tags: gambling

Players of Red Dead Redemption 2: Online (RDO from now on) have been requesting that Poker or other gambling activities be added to the game.

These were expected to be included, as they are present in the Single Player, and in the predecessor Red Dead Redemption.

Many players of the game are suggesting that Poker or other gambling activities can not be included because of legal restrictions on Online Gambling.

Notably, RDO features two forms of currency. In-game "Cash", and "Gold". While Gold can be purchased with real money (Micro-transactions), the In-Game "Cash" has zero interaction with Gold, and can not be purchased with real money. “Cash” can also not be redeemed for real-world money, prizes, or anything else.

Transferring of currency is currently not something available in the game.

“Cash” is earned in all activities of the game, and no prizes would be tied specifically to the game of poker.

If Poker was to be included, and restricted to only In-Game "Cash", would this be an issue regarding Online Gambling laws in a significant number of countries?

Of note:

RDO is an M-Rated (18+) game.

With conservative Pot Limits gambling would be a vastly slower way to earn in-game “Cash” compared to other activities in-game.

Answer (score 5):

> If Poker was to be included, and restricted to only In-Game "Cash", would this be an issue regarding Online Gambling laws in a significant number of countries?

It is hard to give a comprehensive answer because laws vary significantly among countries. I will focus on U.S. law, but other countries very likely adopt a more stringent definition of *gambling* (Muslim nations are at one extreme of the spectrum, since their religion prohibits games of chance).

Under U.S. law (or at least in some of its jurisdictions) the scheme you outline would not meet the legal definition of gambling. The Black's Law Dictionary defines *gamble* as "*[t]o play, or game [...] involv[ing],not only chance, but a hope of gaining something beyond the amount played*".

For a more formalized characterization of gambling, see [*Com. v. Irwin*, 535 Pa. 524, 527 (1993)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/19931059535pa5241987):

> The three elements of gambling are (1) consideration; (2) a result
>   determined by chance rather than skill; and (3) reward

There, the court distinguishes between *reward* and *entertainment* in that in the latter "*the player can never "win" anything other than a prize worth less than the amount he has played*", *Id. at 529*.

This is consistent with the case law from other jurisdictions. See [*Farina v. Kelly*, 147 Conn. 444, 449 (1960)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/1960591147conn4441515):

> [A] lottery is characterized by three constituent elements, namely, a
>   prize, a chance, and a price. [...] [A]s commonly understood, gambling
>   involves not only chance but a hope of gaining something beyond the
>   amount played

Lastly, since

> In-Game "Cash" has zero interaction with Gold, and can not be
>   purchased with real money

it is evident that the purpose of adding Poker the game in the way you describe is pure entertainment, not for a player's expectation of reward as outlined in the aforementioned cases.

Comment: This assumes tht the in-game "cash" not only cannot be bought, but that it cannot be redeemed for actual money or other things of value. It further seems to assume that in-game "cash " cannot be transferred from one player to another, in a way which might be done as part of an out-of-game transaction for real money.. Otherwise the "cash" might be considered a reward beyond entertainment.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Even if in-game "cash" were redeemed for actual money or things of value, it would still be legal as long as the value obtained does not match or exceed the amount the player paid (see the excerpt of *Com. v. Irwin at 529*). Whether or not players arrange for an out-of-game transaction, that is beyond the [online game] supplier's responsibility.

Comment: If "cash" can be redeemed for money or ToV, then a player could accumulate more than the entry fee, unless there is some limit on winnings. If players can trade "cash" out side the game, and the game owners know this does or might well happen for money, they may be facilitating online gambling.

Comment: @David Siegel, it doesn’t assume that the currency can not be bought or redeemed for actual money or things of value. These are facts stated in my question. Regarding the selling of in-game currency for real currency, there is no way to transfer currency (this is actually my assumed reason why it is not included) however poker style games would certainly create a means for this. However, given that “selling” the currency would violate the game’s rules (as is the case in most online games), would that not matter?

Comment: @SchrodingersStat  The question states that "cash" cannot be bought for money. it does **not** say that cash cannot be **redeemed** for money or ToV. If it can't that makes the answer stronger. If there is no practical way for one player to 'buy" the in-game "cash" from another, that makes it stronger yet. If that could plausibly happen, even in violation of the ToS, the game might be regarded by a regulator as facilitating online gambling. Of course I don't know how a regulator would react to such a situation.

Comment: @DavidSiegel "*If players can trade "cash" out side the game, and the game owners know this does or might well happen for money, they may be facilitating online gambling*". That is tantamount to positing that football games may be facilitating gambling just because football organizers know that people can trade/gamble outside or in secret.

Comment: @DavidSiegel The title clearly says “Zero real-world currency involved.” Although I will say, I appreciate the conservative approach. Given Europe has stricter gambling regulations, a strict view is appreciated.

Comment: @Iñaki Viggers : football teams do not run fora where people can wager "points" on games. If they did, regulators might allege that they were in fact promoting gambling with a "wing-and-nudge" cover to keep it apparently legal. I believe that in the past, sports teams have been sanctioned for acts alleged to facilitate gambling.

Comment: @SchrodingersStat : I am just trying to point out the kinds of issues a possibly hostile regulator might raise. Regulators are well aware that some people promote illegal activity while claiming to do no such thing.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I don't follow sports and therefore I cannot comment on whether or why sports teams have been sanctioned as you mention (that is, to what extent --if any-- the sanctions arise from gambling *per se* rather than from schemes attached to it). My points are that (1) U.S. legal definition and case law seem consistent about the distinction between *entertainment* and *reward*; and (2) the legal analyses look at the relation supplier-player, not the relation player-player outside the supplier's scope/control. The supplier's responsibility does not extend to the latter relation.

Comment: @Iñaki Viggers I think you are correct on entertainment vs reward, but if a supplier markets a service with the intent of leveraging or encouraging illicit player-player interactions, then i think the supplier may be held responsible or partly so.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I agree on that. Certain marketing and/or implementation might evidence a supplier's actual intent of gambling or deliberate facilitation thereof.