# Awarding the Top Players of a Video Game

Tags: gambling

Hopefully someone on here can help settle an ongoing debate I've been having with a colleague. We've been discussing different techniques which could be used to entice players of our games to continue playing. At some point the idea of "Awarding" the top X players every month was suggested. A simple example would be "The top 10 players each receive $100".

To me this idea seems like it fits the definition of gambling `play games of chance for money; bet.` which would be illegal in my jurisdiction (unless you were a sanctioned body).

My colleague however insists that it is not gambling because the game requires a level of skill and that the payout would be based on the level of accomplishment that player had achieved. They go on to compare the scenario to when prize money is awarded at e-sports competitions.

I can understand how my colleague could come to this conclusion, but to me it still seems at best a grey area where the law would be concerned (if not full blown black area)

Obviously neither of us posses any real experience dealing with legal issues such as these, so we have pretty much come to a stale mate.

Can anyone here help shed some light onto this topic. Would the situation I have described be considered gambling?

Comment: Where is your location?

Comment: @Putvi United States, Missouri specifically

Comment: Is this an MMO?  How are you generating revenue?

Comment: @hszmv The game we have in mind that this would be implemented for would not be an MMO, but a competitive FPS similar to counter-strike where each player has the same chance of winning a round as every other player and skill is the only determining factor as to who wins the match. Revenue would be generated via a monthly subscription fee to our company for a certain amount (say $1.99 for example). We would then take a percentage of that Revenue and award prize money to the top players (top 10, 100, 1000 not sure where the cutoff would be at this point exactly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Betting would be making a wager, as in saying if this team wins, you get this in a game of chance.

The video game is still a game of chance, but giving a reward is not a bet. MO defines gambling as:

> (4) "Gambling", a person engages in "gambling" when he stakes or risks something of value upon the outcome of a contest of chance or a future contingent event not under his control or influence, upon an agreement or understanding that he will receive something of value in the event of a certain outcome. Gambling does not include bona fide business transactions valid under the law of contracts, including but not limited to contracts for the purchase or sale at a future date of securities or commodities, and agreements to compensate for loss caused by the happening of chance, including but not limited to contracts of indemnity or guaranty and life, health or accident insurance; nor does gambling include playing an amusement device that confers only an immediate right of replay not exchangeable for something of value. Gambling does not include any licensed activity, or persons participating in such games which are covered by sections 313.800 to 313.840; https://law.justia.com/codes/missouri/2011/titlexxxviii/chapter572/section572010

You are free to give a reward to the top player since you are not betting on an outcome, but giving a prize.

That applies to your state only however, if you have players from multiple states and countries you would have to comply with the laws in those areas too.

Comment: If the game has a signiciant chance element, such as loot boxes, that could complicate the situation, however.

Comment: It would not complicate it because the prize is not being given for something of chance. Its just arbitrarily given to the top player.

Comment: If the game is a game of chance, then the prize is being given for something of chance.

Comment: No, because you aren't awarding it based on the chance part. If you and I bet money on who would win and its a game of chance that would be true. The OP isn't betting on one player or the other though.

Comment: If the prize is based on winning, and winning is based on chance, then by transitivity, the prize is based on chance. Do you think craps isn't gambling?

Comment: Craps is gambling because each player places a wager down. If you and your neighbor played craps and then your friend gives you twenty because he respects what you did, he isn't the one gambling.

Comment: The question didn't ask "Would I be considered to be gambling", it asks "Would this be considered gambling". It's a bit frustrating that it took so many comments to get to you clarifying that you are making this distinction between organizing gambling and gambling. And generally, organizing gambling is treated more strictly than participating with gambling, so saying "I'm not gambling, I'm just running a gambling enterprise" is not a good defense.

Comment: No one said hes running gambling either. Gambling is a wager while giving the top person a prize is not.

Comment: You keep wanting to bend this into something its not. He's not placing a bet he can win or loose and is therefore not gambling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93744/discussion-between-acccumulation-and-putvi).

Comment: @Acccumulation to clarify, the system in mind would be that a monthly subscription is collected for providing the game as a service. A player would pay for example $1.99 for the access to the game. This would be collected as revenue by our company. Then on a set schedule we would take a percentage of this revenue and pay award money to the top ranked players (say top 10 for example). Their ranking would be purely based on skill (every player has the same chance of winning a match as any other player). Would also be curious of the outcome of your chat discussion with if one transpired :)

Comment: @commanderZiltoid while in your state its technically not gambling, if you have users from other states or countries, you would have to look at the laws there.

Comment: @Putvi That makes sense. Appreciate the thoroughness you've given this question!

Comment: Thank you for the compliment. I respect anyone making a video game. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Your colleague is right (probably)

Competitions based on skill that offer prizes *to the competitors* are not **gambling** - the $40,000AUD prize for the winner of the [Stawell Gift](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stawell_Gift), the $1.86 million USD to the winner of the [Kentucky Derby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kentucky_Derby), the £38 million GBP for winning the [Premier League](https://www.planetfootball.com/quick-reads/club-by-club-a-breakdown-of-the-2018-19-premier-league-prize-money/), and the various prizes for [Fortnite Leagues](https://dotesports.com/fortnite/news/fortnites-luxe-cup-details-and-prize-pool-distribution-have-been-revealed) are not gambling. Bets made by 3rd parties on the outcome of these (which usually total a *lot* more than the prizes) *are* gambling.

Whether a game is one of skill or chance is a matter of degree. Also, whether a payment is a prize for competing or a wage for working depends on if it is earned through ‘winning’ or ‘grinding’

Notwithstanding, while prizes are more widely legal than gambling, they are usually subject to their only legal requirements.

Answer (score -3):

> Would the situation I have described be considered gambling?

Under U.S. law, the decisive factor is whether a prize --which you quantify at $100-- exceeds the fee(s) a user has to pay you in order to play the game.

For the legal definition of gambling as well as U.S. case law distinguishing between *gambling* and *entertainment*, see [this related answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/38257/would-poker-with-zero-real-world-currency-involved-in-an-m-rated-18-onlin/38260#38260).

Comment: He is in MO, and the MO law says nothing about the fees exceeding the prize.

Comment: @Putvi So what? Other states have similar definitions of *gambling*, and yet their courts apply the criterion of "*prize [being] worth less than the amount he has played*". Particular to Missouri, the three elements of *gambling* listed in [*Veterans of Foreign Wars v. Missouri Gaming Commission*, 260 S.W.3d 388, 391 (2008)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/2008648260jsw3d3881639) strikingly resemble the ones listed in [*Com. v. Irwin*, 535 Pa. 524, 527 (1993)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/19931059535pa5241987).

Comment: The MO case there is about having illegal gambling machines, not what is being discussed here.

Comment: @Putvi You are missing the point. A Missouri court could decide the OP's controversy by adopting the Pennsylvania court's rationale in *Com. v. Irwin* to discern whether or not the $100 reward amounts to gambling. After all, these jurisdictions' prima facie elements of *gambling* are consistent.

Comment: The PA case is also about seizing illegal gambling machines.

Comment: To cite the case, it has to be directly about the issue at hand. Like you would need to find a case about awards to the top players of something.

Comment: @Putvi "*To cite the case, it has to be directly about the issue at hand*". Great! Now go tell the judges in *Com. v. Irwin* that their mention of "*prize worth less than the amount he has played*" has to be directly about the issue at hand because, according to you, their rationale is unrelated to "*seizing illegal gambling machines*".

Comment: You have to read the whole thing. That was stated in reference to this "Thus a gambling device is that which is utilized to facilitate the play for excess value."' They are saying that is what a gambling device is so that justifies the machines being taken.

Comment: @Putvi You just keep missing the point made in *Com v. Irwin*. I'll leave it at that with you because otherwise you'll go on and on. What matters (to me) is that now the OP has access to case law whereby a court identifies *gambling* on the basis of whether or not the prize can exceed the money a player spends on the game. Good bye.

Comment: Well defines a "gambling machine" as that would be accurate.